# How to force line-break only on a space in a title and prevent hypenation with CSS?

Tags: css, space, line-breaks

I would like in CSS force break-line on space and not break words like "Plan[break-line]individual"

[image]

I'm using Flexbox to make an easy responsive code.

**HTML**

```
<section class="card-container">
    <div class="card card-inline text-center">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Plan individual</h4>
                <p class="card-text">€10.00 / year</p>
                <button click="#'">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
    ...                   
</section>
```

**style.css**

```
.card-container{
    display: flex;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.card{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    width: 170px;
}

.card-inline{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: .75rem;
}

.card-block {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

h4.card-title{
    margin: .5rem !important;
    font-size: 100% !important;
}

.text-center{
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

I tried white-space, word-wrap, flex-wrap... without success.
Does anyone have an idea how to prevent the words from being hyphenated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you included doesn't give the result you show in your image, so you must have a CSS rule somewhere else that's causing it.

However, you should be able to override it with the following:

```
h4 {
    hyphens: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's just a part of my code. Thanks, that works !

Comment: @J.BizMai Glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

For a simpler solution, just at a `<br/>` tag to your html in between the words. You can add a `class` if you want to target it with `media queries` to turn the break on and off based on the screen width.

Comment: Impossible to do this in my case. I use a CMS and Administrators inserts text, not HTML tags.

Comment: Which CMS are you using? Most allow you the ability to insert simple tags (`em, strong, br`, etc) in the content

Comment: Firstly, making the admin/editor use HTML tags is undesirable... as its a CMS, its most likely that the text can be edited by users. And regardless of what CMS or process @J.BizMai is using, this isn't a responsive solution - I'd imagine in most cases you wouldn't want the text to wrap when there is enough space for all text.

Comment: @FluffyKitten gave the solution. Why ask to user to add HTML tags when there is an easier css solution ? Your solution is not ergonomical.

Comment: @J.BizMai Your question does not state that your users will be adding input, so how am I supposed to know that your users will be adding input when suggesting an answer? Your question is not formatted correctly. Sorry for the suggestion

Comment: @FluffyKitten A `br` tag can easily be responsive. Just target it through media queries.

Comment: You only require a single CSS rule to ensure the text doesn't hyphenate, so what is the advantage of adding extra HTML tags into what should be a plain-text heading, and then writing media queries to undo that (and "break" the default behaviour of the `<br>` tag), to achieve the same result through a "hack"? Especially when you have to teach your users how and when to use the HTML tags?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I would hardly say the use of a `br` tag is a "hack", by the way. But in this case, yes I would say it is not appropriate to expect the users to know how to implement a `br` tag. As stated, the original question did not state that there was a requirement for the user to input content

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show with the support table, because if hyphenation isn't supported in the first place, then it doesn't matter if we can't override it. "*I would hardly say the use of a br tag is a "hack"*" - it is if you're "breaking" its behaviour to achieve something that already has a specific property to do just that it. But all that's missing the point, which is that the HTML tag doesn't belong in a user-editable title in the first place. Plus you require media queries to "fix" your "fix"!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, like I've said, the question did not state that the content is user-editable. Use hyphens in your CSS if you'd like, you will have issues until it is fully supported. I was merely trying to give a cross-browser suggestion. This is a waste of time.

Comment: You're right, this is a waste of time - user-generated input or not, the added complexity of adding and conditionally removing behaviour for something so trivial is a waste of time.

Comment: No, this is a waste of time, and opinions are subjective. Knowledge is power

Comment: Wow... downvoting me is incredibly petty. Yes, I knew exactly what you meant. And experience is king. As any experienced software engineer will tell you, choosing to add hidden complexity and non-standard behaviour to fix a trivial issue for a tiny minority over a well-supported option is not good practice.